# joining two tables and grouping only if two or more records has same value

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have 2 tables:

```
manifests
id | customer | paid_order | price | payment_method

paid_orders
id | paid

JOIN paid_orders ON manifests.paid_order = paid_order_id
```

> Let's assume this scenario:
>   There are 2 same `customer` but has different `payment_method`.

```
customer | paid_order | price | payment_method |  paid  |
    1    |      1     | 200   |        0       |  200   |
    1    |     NULL   | 100   |        1       |  NULL  |
    2    |     NULL   | 150   |        1       |  NULL  |
```

I only want to `GROUP BY customer` but also **PICK** only the `payment_method` of `0` **only** if there are two same customer.

Expected result:

```
customer | paid_order | price | payment_method |  paid  |
    1    |      1     | 200   |        0       |  200   |
    2    |     NULL   | 150   |        1       |  NULL  |
```

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure this is an _exact_ duplicate here, because there is some business logic which must be assumed to write a query like that.

Comment: MANY `manifests` records can have same `paid_order` ids.
By ignoring `payment_method = 1` we can focus on `customers`.
But I don't want to eliminate all the `payment_method = 1`, because I also need the customer from it.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB? These are different DBMS. And then, which version? As of MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.0 you can rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: mysql 8.
I don't need to know the row number.

Comment: I wanted to post an acording answer, but could not as your request has been marked duplicate unfortunately.

Comment: I'll try that given solution.

Comment: Tim's answer is also good (but see my comment on it). However, window functions like `ROW_NUMBER` are great, and it's worth reading up on these anyway.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm surprised you don't have a gold medal in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to always select the record from one, or possibly more, customer records where the `payment_method` has the minimum value:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM manifest m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT customer, MIN(payment_method) AS min_payment_method
    FROM manifest
    GROUP BY customer
) m2
    ON m1.customer = m2.customer AND m1.payment_method = m2.min_payment_method;
```

This logic should work, because if a `payment_method` of zero be present, then this record would be targeted.  Otherwise, the one value record would be targeted.

Comment: Your answer is identical to linked solutions

Comment: While the answer is good, I would always prefer to have criteria in the `WHERE` clause for the sake of readability: `select * from manifests where (customer, payment_method) in (select customer, min(payment_method) …`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner But what about performance?  Anyway, most DBs do not support that tuple syntax.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: You are right mentioning performance. MySQL was kind of notorious for bad performance on `IN` clauses once. I'd hope this is a matter of the past, though. I always strive to get my queries as readable as possible and only alter them when performance issues actually occur. And if the optimizer does a good job here, both queries should result in the same execution plan, of course.